# Wireless USB Mouse Stopped Working

Tags: usb, wireless, mouse

I formatted my SD card, did a fresh install of Raspbian using NOOBS and started following [a guide](http://geeks.noeit.com/mount-an-smb-network-drive-on-raspberry-pi/) to access files from my Ubuntu media PC on my Pi. I actually didn't have any luck getting that to work, but that's another post.

Anyways, I was chugging along on a wireless USB keyboard and mouse, and all of a sudden the mouse stopped working; I'm pretty sure it was right after issuing the `sudo mount -a` command. The keyboard continues to work fine, but the mouse is  a total no go. I've tried reverting my `/etc/fstab` file, restarting, etc, but none of it seems to have an effect.

Since the system is so bare to begin with, I'm tempted to just install from scratch, but it would be ideal to get to the bottom of the problem, in case it happens again.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried a powered usb hub for the mouse wireless dongle?

Comment: No, I have not tried a powered USB hub.